(weak necessity) proof a collection is closed under Modus Ponens from prior assumptions
I am looking for help understanding Exercise 7.3 from A Philosophical Introduction to Higher-order Logics by Bacon. The ultimate goal of the exercise is to prove the right-to-left direction of the biconditional:

$X$ is a weak necessity if and only if $X^*\top$ and $X^* \forall_{t}pq(X(p \to q) \to Xp \to Xq)$.

Where:
$$X^* := \lambda p. \forall_t q(\forall_{t \to t} Y( Yp \:\wedge\: \forall_t r (Yr \to Y(Xr)) \to Yq) \to q) $$
In case there is any confusion, the subscripts under the universals indicate variable types, $X^*\top$ means that $X^*$ contains all propositional tautologies, and the second assumption is equivalent to K $XX^*$. On to the problem:

a) Prove that $X^*$ is closed under modus ponens; i.e. show that MP $X^*$.
$$
\text{MP} X^* := \forall_t pq (X^*p \:\wedge\: X^*(p \to q) \to X^*q)
$$
I had two different instincts for this problem and I believe neither of them to be successful. My first mode of thinking was to use the assumption of $\text{K}XX^*$ which basically states that $X^*$ is a collection of propositions that contains the proposition $\forall_{t}pq(X(p \to q) \to Xp \to Xq)$.
However, this does not guarantee that $X^*$ itself is closed under M.P. right? Only that it contains the propositions, closed by MP, prefixed by $X$. It would require knowing that $X$ was a weak necessity already to show that all propositions in $X$ are true.
My second thought was that, given $X^*\top$, $X^*$ is a set of sentences containing all propositional tautologies. Hence, it stands to reason that $X^*$ contains the proposition: $p \to (p \to q) \to q$
My thought was then, under the assumption that $X^*p \wedge X^*(p \to q)$, there should be a way to derive $X^*q$. However, I was frustrated to discover that my attempted solution tacitly assumes that $X^*$ is already closed under M.P.
ANY ADVICE FOR (a)???

b) Prove that $X^*$ is closed under necessitation for $X$, i.e. show that $\text{N} X X^*$.
$$
\text{N} X X^* := \forall_t p (X^*p \to X^*(Xp))
$$
again, for this problem I assumed that the solution had to do with the definition of $X^*$, particularly the section having to deal with prefixing $X$:

$ Yp \:\wedge\: \forall_t r (Yr \to Y(Xr)) $

But this section is within a conditional, so I do not think I can derive closure under prefixing from this, because $X^*p:=$
$$
\forall_t q(\forall_{t \to t} Y( Yp \:\wedge\: \forall_t r (Yr \to Y(Xr)) \to Yq) \to q)
$$
ANY ADVICE FOR (b)?????

I believe to know the solution to (c) and (d). but I would really appreciate any help on the first two parts. Thank you
